# How do I escape special characters in Org mode?

Tags: org-mode

Here is a bit of Org code:

```
Here's a bit of OCaml: ~let x' = 1 in x' + x'~.
Many ~x~s in there, no?
And this one is worse: ~x ~!~ x <> 0~
```

Exporting to PDF yields this:

[image: rendered]

How do I

- Escape the `'` to fix the first line?
- Escape the `s` to fix the second line?
- Escape the `~` to fix the third line?

I did not find any mention of this is the org manual.

Comment: Did you see this man page: http://orgmode.org/org.html#Emphasis-and-monospace

Comment: @EmacsUser: Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Escape the ' to fix the first line?

Works for me with the development version.

> Escape the s to fix the second line?

I don't think that's possible ATM in Org syntax.  You might need something like `@@latex:\texttt{x}s@@`.

> Escape the ~ to fix the third line?

```
=x ~!~ x <> 0=
```

Comment: Re the third one: that won't do; I do need a difference between Code and Verbatim.

Comment: how about `src_ocaml{x ~!~ x <> 0}`?

Comment: Woops. Not sure how I missed your comment. I just came across these. Feel free to expand your answer, and I'll delete mine.

Comment: Although `src_` is broken as well: `src_c{int main \{}` keeps the escape character in there, and `src_c{a{}b}` stops at the first closing brace...

Comment: You were right about the first one: it was fixed in org 9.

Answer (score 4):

Using [inline code blocks](http://orgmode.org/manual/Structure-of-code-blocks.html) fixes some of these issues; I'm not sure why I didn't come across them before:

```
#+PROPERTY: header-args :exports code

Here's a bit of OCaml: src_ocaml{let x' = 1 in x' + x'}.
Many src_ocaml{x}s in there, no?
And this one is worse: src_ocaml{x ~!~ x <> 0}.
```

And the output:

```
Here's a bit of OCaml: \texttt{let x' = 1 in x' + x'}.
Many \texttt{x}s in there, no?
And this one is worse: \texttt{x \textasciitilde{}!\textasciitilde{} x <> 0}.
```

It's not a panacea, of course: both `src_c{int main \{}` and `src_c{a{}b}` are broken...